# Why does vapor cloud deploy think I'm running swift 3.1.0? As you can see, I'm running Swift 5.2

Tags: swift, xcode, vapor

```
$ swift --version
Apple Swift version 5.2 (swiftlang-1103.0.32.1 clang-1103.0.32.29)
$ vapor cloud deploy
...
swift-package: error: Package requires minimum Swift tools version 5.2.0. Current Swift tools version is 3.1.0
```

I beg to differ.
Also at the top of Package.swift I have:

```
// swift-tools-version:5.2
```

Comment: Vapor cloud has been closed

Answer (score 1):

vapor cloud was closed a few months ago, but a good alternative is Heroku, you can find a guide to deply it here.

https://docs.vapor.codes/4.0/deploy/heroku/

or if you are using vapor 3 here:

https://docs.vapor.codes/3.0/deploy/heroku/